# Why updating object in array is not working in VUE?

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, mutation

I'm trying to make an update and I managed to do it in the firebase, but in the store is not updating. Here is my code

```
editCar() {
      let result = this.balmUI.validate(this.formData);
      let { valid, message } = result;
      this.message = message;
      console.log(`Vrei sa editezi masina: ${this.formData.vehicle}`);
      console.log(utils.url);

      if (valid) {
        let data = {
          vehicle: this.formData.vehicle,
          color: this.formData.color,
          fuel: this.formData.fuel,
          status: this.formData.status,
          price: this.formData.price,
        };

        let requestParameters = { ...utils.globalRequestParameters };
        let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
        requestParameters.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
        requestParameters.method = "PUT";
        requestParameters.body = JSON.stringify(data);

        fetch(utils.url + "cars/" + this.formData.id, requestParameters)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.message);
            if (
              res.message === "Decoding error!" ||
              res.message === "Your token expired!"
            ) {
              console.log("nu ai voie!");
            } else {
              data.id = res.id;
              this.$store.dispatch("editCar", data);
              this.$router.push("/");
            }
          });
      }
```

This is the index from store, which contais my mutation and action. Anything else is working properly

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cars: [],
    isAuthentif: false
  },
  getters: {
    cars: state => {
      return state.cars
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_AUTH: (state, status) => {
      state.isAuthentif = status
    },
    SET_CARS: (state, cars) => {
      state.cars = cars
    },
    ADD_CAR: (state, car) => {
      state.cars.push(car)
    },
    DELETE_CAR: (state, id) => {
      var index = state.cars.findIndex(car => car.id == id)
      state.cars.splice(index, 1);
    },
    EDIT_CAR: (state, car) => {
      state.cars.forEach(c => {
        if(c.id === car.id) {
          c = car;
        }
      })
    }
  },
  actions: {
    login: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('SET_AUTH', payload)
    },
    fetchCars: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('SET_CARS', payload)
    },
    addCar: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('ADD_CAR', payload)
    },
    deleteCar: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('DELETE_CAR', payload)
    },
    editCar: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('EDIT_CAR', payload)
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

EDIT_CAR is the problem, I think.
What is wrong? Why it is not updating on the screen.
I've also tried to use this https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#object-style-commit
like this `c = {...c, car}` but is not working

Comment: What is `state.cars`? Is it an array of primitives, or an array of objects?

Comment: Array of objects @Terry

Comment: Is it possible to share a [mcve] instead?

Comment: My object from array list is updated in the database, but not is the app page. In the app page is updated after manual refresh @Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the mutation. The problem is in your editCar() in here `this.$store.dispatch("editCar", data);`
You put data, and with **vehicle, color, fuel, status and price** and then in your mutation you verify ID. You didn't pass any id. You cand make a new object if you don't want you id, like this:

```
editCar() {
      let result = this.balmUI.validate(this.formData);
      let { valid, message } = result;
      this.message = message;
      console.log(`Vrei sa editezi masina: ${this.formData.vehicle}`);
      console.log(utils.url);

      if (valid) {
        let data = {
          vehicle: this.formData.vehicle,
          color: this.formData.color,
          fuel: this.formData.fuel,
          status: this.formData.status,
          price: this.formData.price,
        };

        let requestParameters = { ...utils.globalRequestParameters };
        let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
        requestParameters.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
        requestParameters.method = "PUT";
        requestParameters.body = JSON.stringify(data);

        fetch(utils.url + "cars/" + this.formData.id, requestParameters)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.message);
            if (
              res.message === "Decoding error!" ||
              res.message === "Your token expired!"
            ) {
              console.log("nu ai voie!");
            } else {
              let newData = {
                id: this.formData.id,
                vehicle: data.vehicle,
                color: data.color,
                fuel: data.fuel,
                status: data.status,
                price: data.price,
              };
              this.$store.dispatch("editCar", newData);
              this.$router.push("/");
            }
          });
      }
    },
```

Also in your mutation cand make something like this:

```
EDIT_CAR: (state, car) => {
      Object.assign(state.cars[state.cars.findIndex(c => c.id === car.id)], car);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change your EDIT_CAR mutation to:

```
const index = state.cars.findIndex(x => x.id === car.id)
state.cars.splice(index, 1, car)
```

If you haven't done already, place a console.log(car) at the beginning of the mutation so you make sure it gets called and the car payload is what you expect.

Comment: In console log is the payload car I expect, but in my list the value is not changed :/

Comment: Maybe the problem is not from the mutation. Maybe it is the way I make this update. I have a list of cars and when I click the edit button of one car, I redirect to another router where I have a form in which I transfer a parameter with my car, and then I came back to my list which is not changed

Comment: Update, the problem is in the mutation. My state.cars is not changed and I dont understant why. Also, your answer is not good because it adds me another car in my list instead of replacing it

Comment: Well no that replaces the object it doesn't add one. And it's better than using Object.assign. If id was not set in payload means data.id = res.id was the problem.